# Rails 4 relation tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

Hello I am attempting to add categories to my posts and I am a little confused on how to set up the relation for this one.

Should a post have_many categories or should a category have_many posts?

Ideally what I want to do is have one table that I seed with particular categories which in my head is a table with id's and a simple alias column for each category name.

When making a post I want a select with all the categories in place and just assign a value. So if I picked value = 1 it should probably place the "1" into the categories_id column which gets referenced and I know that 1 = Some category.

Maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case,it should be **`categories has_many posts`** and **`post belongs to category`**

```
Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy 

end

Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :category

end
```

By giving this,you should be having a **`category_id(Foreign key)`** in your posts table.

So when you are creating a post,you can able to select categories through a **`collection_select`** or **`select`**.

Hope it helps!